# Titanium not load menu and menuItem visible/not visible

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have two problems with the menu.
The menu is created by .xml file.

example:

```
<Menu>
<MenuItem id = "search" onclick = "search" />
<MenuItem id = "add" onclick = "add" />
</ Menu>
```

1) The first problem is that sometimes strangely the menu is not loaded, that is, do not see the buttons.
Can you tell me why.

2) The second problem is that I have a menuItem field normally not visible, only determiate conditions in the field will have to be visible.
Could you tell me how I can have access to the field.

.xml

```
<MenuItem id = "profile" />
```

.tss

```
"#profile[platform=android]": {
      title: "Profile",
         icon: "/global/profile.png"
         showAsAction: Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS,
         visible: false
    }
```

.js

```
$ .profile.visible = True;
```

Error message: Can not set property visible of undefined.

I apologize for my bad English.

Thank you.

Edit:

Example:

```
         var activity = $ .index.activity;
         activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu = function (e) {
             var favoriteGroup e.menu.add = ({
                 title: "Profile",
                 icon: "/global/profile.png"
                 showAsAction: Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS,
             });
             favoriteGroup.addEventListener ('click', function () {
                Alloy.createController ("favorite_group", args) .getView (). Open ();
             });
         };
         activity.invalidateOptionsMenu ();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution for issue 1:

You will need to reload the menus created in Alloy XML. Mostly people create menus in .js file in window's open events so that they can be created only after a window is properly opened:

To create menus in .js file, do it like this:

***- Solution using window.js only***

```
    var searchMenu, addMenu;

    $.window.addEventListener('open', function () {
        var activity = $.window.activity;

        activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function (e) {
            searchMenu = e.menu.add({
                title: 'Search',
                showAsAction: Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            });
            searchMenu.addEventListener('click', function () {
                 // open my profile here or do other tasks
            });

            addMenu = e.menu.add({
                title: 'Add',
                showAsAction: Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            });
        };

        // this is the code to validate menu items once they are added into an activity
        activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    });
```

***- Solution using window.xml + window.js***

So, to solve your issue no. 1, you might need to call this code in your controller file of that xml (activity is only available once a window is opened, so use open event):

***window.xml***

```
<Menu platform="android">
    <MenuItem id="MENU_SEARCH" title="Search" onClick='search' showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS" />
    <MenuItem id="MENU_ADD"   title="Add" onClick='add' showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS" />
</Menu>
```

***window.js***

```
$.window.addEventListener('open', function () {
    $.window.activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
});
```

### Solution for issue 2:

It could be due to 2 reasons:

- Your tss is not written correctly like you have written in your question.
- You are accessing the $.profile menu-item even before it's opened. (see code in Solution 1). So set a timeout in window open event when you are setting the property.

**window.js**

```
$.window.addEventListener('open', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.profile.visible = true;
    }, 400);
});
```

**.tss**

```
"#profile[platform=android]": {
     title: "Profile",
     icon: "/global/profile.png",
     showAsAction: Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS,
     visible: false
}
```

Comment: I thank you infinitely for having responded to my question.
I tried as you said, but it does not work at all.
The reason is that "onCreateOptionsMenu", delete everything that is created as a menu with .xml.
So I adopted as a solution to use "onPrepareOptionsMenu", it seems to be working currently.

Comment: But with a problem that does not know how to explain why.
It appears on the menu twice menuItem created via js code.
In your opinion what is the reason of this problem?

Comment: I have added and modified my code in answer to match your code. Please look on the above code and try to understand how Menu items are created in Android and how they need to be recreated in case they are not showing in some cases using XML.

Comment: Do not use onPrepareOptionsMenu when you are creating MenuItem in XML.